# Not responding in tkinter screen

Tags: python, tkinter

Iam building a project tkinter.
Here my Code

```
from tkinter import *
screen=Tk()
screen.geometry('500x300+400+200')
def play():
    from playsound import playsound
    playsound("music.mp3")
screen.title("Simple project")
btn=Button(screen,text='play',width=20,command=play).place(x=340,y=260)
screen.mainloop()
```

And when I click button "play" then tkinter screen is **Not responding**.

[image]

So how can I fix it.

Thank you

Comment: You can set `block` option to False: `playsound(..., block=False)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `threading` module.

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

screen=Tk()
screen.geometry('500x300+400+200')
def play():
    from playsound import playsound
    playsound("music.mp3")

def start_play():
    t=Thread(target=play)
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

screen.title("Simple project")
btn=Button(screen,text='play',width=20,command=start_play).place(x=340,y=260)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: @WarsLand consider accepting the answer if it solvs the problem ```:-)```

Comment: @WarsLand  THANK YOU  `:-) `